# Como visualizar el cargo y departamento de un usuario en una sola consulta?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me interesa mostrar la información del usuario, el departamento y el cargo, tengo una consulta que me presenta los funcionarios y el departamento pero me gustaría mostrar de una ves el cargo.

```
return DB::table('funcionario as f')
        ->join('dep_has_fun as dhf','dhf.funcionario_idfuncionario','=','f.idfuncionario')
        ->join('departamento as d', 'd.iddepartamento','=','dhf.departamento_iddepartamento')
        ->where('dhf.estado','=',1)->get();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se me ocurrió hacer es: a la tabla `de_has_fun` añadir la clave de cargo, de esta forma en una sola consulta obtendría el departamento y cargo al cual pertenece, pero no estoy seguro si es lo correcto. Estoy atento a cualquier comentario y sugerencia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Revisando el codigo de ejemplo que colocas te hace falta hacer los joins para obetener el cargo (solo tienes los join para departamento), puedes probar los siguiente:

```
return DB::table('funcionario as f')
            ->join('dep_has_fun as dhf','f.idfuncionario','=','dhf.funcionario_idfuncionario')
            ->join('departamento as d','dhf.departamento_iddepartamento','=','d.iddepartamento')
            ->join('fun_has_car as fhc','f.idfuncionario','=','fhc.funcionario_idfuncionario')
            ->join('cargo as c','fhc.cargo_idcargo','=','c.idcargo')
            ->where('dhf.estado','=',1)->get();
```

No esta de mas decirte que pueder utlizar Eloquent y las relaciones que te provee Laravel que te hara todo mas facil.

Comment: Esta respuesta no aprovecha las funcionalidades de Laravel ni de Eloquent, para trabajar de esa manera, es mejor no utilizar Laravel.

Comment: @Shaz tienes toda la razon y si revisas al final de la solucion incluyo el consejo de utilizar el ORM de Laravel que resumiria ese tipo de consultas en pocas lineas de codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo en la estructura de tu base de datos, un funcionario puede tener más de un departamento y más de un cargo.

---

Si tus relaciones están definidas correctamente en Eloquent (siguiendo su documentación al pie de la letra), con esta sintaxis obtienes lo que buscas:

```
$funcionario = Funcionario::with(['departamentos', 'cargos'])->get();
```

Y obtienes los cargos y departamentos de cada funcionario de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($funcionario->departamentos as $depto) {
    echo $depto->dep_nombre;
}


foreach ($funcionario->cargos as $cargo) {
    echo $cargo->car_nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo dar una solución con SQL y ya lo adaptas. Básicamente te faltan JOINS por lo que veo, he creado las tablas del diagrama con oracle SQL developer y realizado la consulta para comprobar su funcionamiento:

```
SELECT f.*,d.dep_nombre,c.car_nombre 
FROM funcionario f 
JOIN dep_has_fun dhf ON f.IDFUNCIONARIO=dhf.FUNCIONARIO_IDFUNCIONARIO 
JOIN departamento2 d ON dhf.DEPARTAMENTO_IDDEPARTAMENTO=d.IDDEPARTAMENTO
JOIN fun_has_car fhc ON fhc.funcionario_idfuncionario=f.IDFUNCIONARIO
JOIN cargo c ON c.IDCARGO=fhc.cargo_idcargo ;
```

Comment: Esto realmente no responde la pregunta, en Laravel las consultas funcionan de una forma más bien distinta a SQL puro (aún si es practicamente el mismo lenguaje), de hecho es mucho más sencillo hacer esto en Laravel.